# checksum of a distributed variable

Tags: parallel-computing, fortran, mpi

Let say I have N computers and 2 N-by-N matrices distributed across them called A and B. Matrix A is row distributed while B is column distributed. Therefore, processor i knows

```
A(i,1:N) and B(1:N,i)
```

Do you know an efficient way to determine if A and B are identical that scales well to many processors? (some kind of checksum function for distributed variables that does not depend on how the variable is scattered)

Background is I am working with a fortran code based on MPI.

Comment: Following the answer from @WolfgangBangerth : although A and B are often double precision real numbers, from a binary perspective, those numbers can be casted to integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can be "pretty sure" that the two matrices are the same if their hash values are the same. What you will have to do is compute a hash that is *additive* (possibly including modulo operations) so that it can be computed efficiently in parallel.

For example, if I may for a moment assume that the matrices have integer entries, then the (not particularly good) hash function
$$
  h(A) = \left(\sum_{i,j} (i^2+j)A_{ij} \right) \text{mod} P
$$
with some large integer P is one such function because the modulo operation can be done in parallel by each processor based on their respective parts of the matrix. You then just have to do a global sum reduction module $P$ at the end.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. My matrices are made from double precision real numbers, but from a binary perspective, they can be interpreted as integers.

Comment: Have you considered integer overflow may happen inside the sum? (especially when casting real numbers to integers)

Comment: That's why you need the modulo operation, of course with some $P$ that is less than the largest integer you can represent. (Or a defined way in which overflow happens, e.g., by wrapping around, as in unsigned integer arithmetic. In that case, the modulo operation would be implicit, and with $P=2^{32}$, for example.)

Comment: Is there a simple reference where I can read about this?

Comment: Books about basic computer science techniques will have a discussion of hash functions.